From where does the IP addresses are assigned to Cluster Drivers in Azure Databricks?
Accessing SQL DB through using Databricks Notebook
I have created a databricks workspace using a vnet address range 10.90.X.X/24. I am trying to run a notebook which has the content shown in above image.
This code basically helps me to access a table 'Employee' inside my SQL server database.
As you know, to run a notebook you need to attach a cluster to it. Everytime I start the cluster, it tells me to whitelist some new client IP starting with 4.221.x.x or 102.37.x.x or some other.
I assumed that the clusters will be assigned an ip from the vnets address range. But doesnt look like that.
Its getting difficult to whitelist the databricks cluster driver ip again & again in SQL firewall rule.
Am I missing on something due to which cluster drivers don't use the ip from vnet range.
From where are these ip getting assigned to the drivers?
Error
Weird thing is, if I go into the cluster compute settings it shows the vnet ip's. Then why the same range ips are not used by the cluster drivers while running a notebook?
Compute cluster info

Instead of adding IP address again to sql server firewall rule check option Allow azure services and resources to the server.

Cannot open server '****' requested by the login. Client with IP address '*****' is not allowed to access the server. To enable access, use the Azure Management Portal or run sp_set_firewall_rule on the master database to create a firewall rule for this IP address or address range. It may take up to five minutes for this change to take effect. 

Here is the issue from sql server side. SQL server is not allowing the Ip address that may be the reason to get above error. To provide access to sql server from Azure resource you have Allow azure services and resources to the server option at sql server networking tab check that option and save it as shown below:

Then you don't need to whitelist the ip address again and again to sql server while reading data from sql server in azure databricks. You can access the data successfully using below code successfully:
jdbcHostname = "<servername>.database.windows.net"     
jdbcPort = 1433    
jdbcDatabase = "<dbname>"     
jdbcUsername = "<username>"             
jdbcPassword = "<password>"            
jdbcDriver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"     
table = "Students"
jdbcUrl = f"jdbc:sqlserver://{jdbcHostname}:{jdbcPort};databaseName={jdbcDatabase}"
df = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("driver", jdbcDriver).option("url", jdbcUrl).option("dbtable", table).option("user", jdbcUsername).option("password", jdbcPassword).load()



HI Bhavani,
We are trying to connect from on-prem network. We need to add an IP Address in our on-prem network so databricks can access different source.
Hence, we are looking for a way for Databricks to have a static IP.
Have you experienced that?
